# Redirecting dynamic addresses in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I hope someone can help me,

I have a set of pages that looks like this:

```
www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/contact.htm
```

and another set of pages that looks like this:

```
www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/index.htm
```

The only thing that is different is the contact and index words at the end of my dynamic urls.

Of course every page is different, other cities, countries and so on.

what I want is to redirect all

```
www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/contact.htm
```

to

```
www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/index.htm
```

dynamically.

This is the code I have today but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).ht$ city.php?c=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/index.html$ bizlist.php?state=$1&c=$2&first=0

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/index-(.*).html$ bizlist-alpha.php?state=$1&c=$2&alpha=$3&first=0

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/index-(.*)-(.*).html$ bizlist-alpha.php?state=$1&c=$2&alpha=$3&first=$4

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/businesses-(.*).html$ bizlist.php?state=$1&c=$2&first=$3

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-County/(.*)/(.*)/index.htm$ business.php?s=$1&telephone=$5&c=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-County/(.*)/(.*)/index.htm$ ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-County/(.*)/(.*)/index.htm$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-County/(.*)/(.*)/$ business.php?s=$1&telephone=$5&c=$2
```

Comment: You're missing the most important thing: a description of what exactly it is that you want to do! Redirect what to what?

Comment: that's the last paragraph on the question: "what I want":      what I want is to redirect all www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/contact.htm to www.example.com/country/city/county/business-name/listing-id/index.htm dynamically.

Comment: Ah, hard to spot among the inlined gobbledygook. The reformatting did wonders here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/contact.htm$ $1/index.htm [R,L]
```

Don't make your regular expressions hyper specific when a catchall `.*` will do. You're only interested in the last part, so only match the last part. Of course, if you have *other* URLs ending in `contact.htm` which you don't want to redirect, you need to make the regex more specific as appropriate.

Note also that the order of rules matters; you need to insert this rule before any other rewriting happens which will cause it to not match anymore.